# Simple digit extraction with regex

Tags: regex

I've got a simple input line :

```
"12234542","444232343","3323131"
```

Same string is always received , I'd like to split these into groups with regex such as I'd like for group1 to match `12234542` , group two to match `444232343`, and group 3 to  match `3323131`

Tried this and not working :

```
[^"]([0-9]+)[^"],[^"]([0-9]+)[^"],[^"]([0-9]+)[^"]
```

Comment: Do you always get exactly three numbers? Is using regexp a requirement. It doesn't look like the best solution if you have some other string operations like split at your disposal.

Comment: @KL-7 yes I always get 3 numbers

Comment: Well, then solution from hochl is all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want to match a group of three such digit strings? Then use

```
"(\d+)","(\d+)","(\d+)"
```

as pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
/"([^"]+)","([^"]+)","([^"]+)"/
```